# hasClass not working, showing div on each album box click to show images by replacing class

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="album 1"></div>
<div class="album 2"></div>
<div class="album 3"></div>
<div class="album 4"></div>

<script>

$('.album').click(function(){
   $('.album').each(function(){
  $('enlarge-album-box').css('display','none');

  if($(this).hasClass('1')){
     alert('this is');
     $('.enlarge-album-box').show().css('background','red');
  }
  else if($(this).hasClass('2')){
     alert('now this');
     $('.enlarge-album-box').show().css('background','green');
  }
  });

});
</script>
```

i am creating a album box which will display related images in the opening box by     clicking on each album type, iv'e given each album a different class like 1 2 3 4 so i want to display different property in the enlarge box on clicking on each different class

Comment: What is not working? Why the each loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need of the each loop, also the selector used for hiding the element is wrong

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('.album').click(function () {
        $('.enlarge-album-box').hide();

        if ($(this).hasClass('1')) {
            $('.enlarge-album-box').show().css('background', 'red');
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('2')) {
            $('.enlarge-album-box').show().css('background', 'green');
        }
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VvSvr/)

Comment: Thanks arun, one more thing i want to ask to you, if i want that mouse is clicked anywhere out of this thing on body on anywhere else i want to hide those enlarge boxes.
so how can i do it ?

Comment: you have not replied me on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('enlarge-album-box').css('display','none');
```

should be

```
$('.enlarge-album-box').css('display','none');
```

or

```
$('#enlarge-album-box').css('display','none'); //matter what is in your case id or class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="album one"></div>
<div class="album two"></div>
<div class="album three"></div>
<div class="album four"></div>

<script>

$('.album').click(function(){
   $('.album').each(function(){
  $('enlarge-album-box').css('display','none');

  if($(this).hasClass('one')){
     alert('this is');
     $('.enlarge-album-box').show().css('background','red');
  }
  else if($(this).hasClass('two')){
     alert('now this');
     $('.enlarge-album-box').show().css('background','green');
  }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function () {
        $('.album').on('click',function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('.enlarge-album-box').hide();

            if ($(this).hasClass('1')) {
                $('.enlarge-album-box').show().css('background', 'red');
            } else if ($(this).hasClass('2')) {
                $('.enlarge-album-box').show().css('background', 'green');
            }
        });
    })
    $('.enlarge-album-box').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function(){
         $('.enlarge-album-box').slideUp();
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MVh9U/1/)

Comment: thank buddy, but one more thing i want to ask, i wish ti this enlarge box to be close if mouse is clicked outside of this thing anywhere on body

Comment: @PratyushGoyal ask dude

Comment: ya ..  i want this enlarge-album-box to be hide if clicked anywhere on body